# Correctly handling Incremental Consent for Azure AD Open ID Connect

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an application that is registered with Azure AD. I want to use incremental consent so that users don't have to consent to all permissions up front. I attempted to use the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class to generate the URL. This works fine, but afterwards, the user is redirected back to `/signin-oidc`. This is fine as I can provide a URL in the initial redirect to get the user back to where they need to be.

The issue is that the `/signin-oidc` endpoint throws an error indicating that no Correlation ID was found. I assume it's looking for this value in a cookie. I started down the path to create the cookie, but that seems fragile to me (what if the OIDC library changes how it creates the cookie in a future version). I feel like I should be able to return a specific `IActionResult` (or something similar) to signal to the OIDC middleware that the app needs additional permissions from the user (and the OIDC middleware will issue the redirect and properly handle the result from Azure AD).

Am I going down the wrong path? I haven't found any good examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a good example. The short answer is to return a `ChallengeResult`. Use the overload (either method if in a `Controller` or constructor if elsewhere) that takes an `AuthenticationProperties` object.

The most important part is to use `SetParameter` with key of "scope" and value that is a list of the scopes you need.

In this example, the author wrapped the logic inside an attribute:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/AuthorizeForScopesAttribute.cs